# C - passing wrong pointer type to function

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning about Undefined behavior in C. Now I got a little code snippet and thinking of if it is undefined behavior or not.

In my example I got a `char *ptr.` Let's imagine it has been initialized correctly.

Second, I got a function which takes a `(double *dPtr)`. If I now pass my char pointer to that function, will it result in UB? Firstly, I doubt it.

If I now use that pointer in my function and access the value, will that result in undefined behavior or will it just be interpreted as double value? Even if the value is incorrect, can the char be interpreted as double, which is normal behavior?

```
//Passing char* instead of double*
void foo(double* dPtr) {
    //UB ?
    double d = (* dPtr - 15.0)/2.0;
}

int main()
{
  char *string = "Hello World";
  foo(string);
}
```

Comment: In Go (C-like language), it's imposible to pass mis-matching type of pointer to function. In short, compiler catches all UB in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 6.5 7 says:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

Accessing an array of `char` as a `double` satisfies none of these, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Additionally, when the pointer to `char` is converted to a pointer to `double`, if it is not suitably aligned for a `double`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, by 6.3.2.3 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…

Comment: Excellent post, Eric! However, if behaviour is "not defined by the C standard" does it become *undefined* or *implementation defined*? (Posted before your edit about misaligned pointers.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Regarding the last quote: so it may result in Undefined behavior if it is wrong aligned?

Comment: @AdrianMole: The C standard uses “undefined” to mean the standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior. I often avoid using “undefined” for that, as behavior may be undefined by the C standard but defined by other specifications or conditions.

Comment: @AdrianMole Anything for which the behavior is not defined has undefined behavior. It has to be explicitly noted as implementation-defined for it to be implementation-defined.

Comment: @davidev: The short version is that it’s UB even if it is aligned. (The alignment thing is about pointer conversion, where doing a misaligned `(double*)string` is illegal without even dereferencing it.)